# "Include Glance Screen" Watch OS 2.0

Tags: apple-watch, xcode7-beta5

I am creating a new watch app and there is an option "Include Glance Screen". I tried searching for it but not able to get it what it do. What effect it will make on checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create a GlanceController source code file and a Glance interface controller in the storyboard.

If you need generic info about glances, you can check:

https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/app-components/#glances